# "Privileges" / "badges" links in achievements dropdown only appear in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, achievements-dialog, broken-link

I just noticed these very handy links on my achievements dropdown:

[image]

*Yay!* I thought. *This looks really useful!* It's always a pain to get to the privileges page by going via the help centre.

Only problem is, this screenshot was taken in **chat**, the only part of SE where there *aren't* "privileges" and "badges" pages. (The links redirect to https://chat.stackexchange.com/help/privileges and https://chat.stackexchange.com/help/badges, both of which give me "Page Not Found".) And when I look at my achievements dropdown on any main site, i.e. a place where those links would actually take me somewhere useful, they don't appear. I checked this on one site where I'm a moderator; one where I'm not a mod but have all rep-based privileges; and two sites (one graduated, one beta) where I don't yet have all the privileges. Nix on all of them.

Those links should either **appear on the dropdown from main sites too** (preferable) or **not appear at all** (since they're certainly useless in chat, the only place where they currently appear).

Comment: this. is. funny.

Comment: They also appear on SO, so your last statement is incorrect...

Comment: @Mithrandir I don't have an SO account.

Comment: Oops. Fixing it. ...at least it was DRY coded?

Comment: Nick Craver, the new competitor of Bill the Chameleon in terms of swiftness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry this took a minute - I was fixing some local environment oddities while I was in there. The links are now appropriately tied to the new header. These changes are live.